# Why does an AWS EC2 instance need public and private DNS?

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I am creating my own VPC and was reading some documentation.  AWS documentation for DNS with VPC [(click here to view)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-dns.html) says

> To enable an EC2 instance to be publicly accessible, it must have a public IP address, a DNS hostname, and DNS resolution.

Is this true? Why?

Is a private IP address in combination with an elastic IP address not enough to access the instance publicly and privately?

Comment: Have you tried it? Have you considered that they just consider an IP address without a DNS name useless enough that they have written "must have" where "should have" would be more correct? (I don't know this, just a guess).

Comment: @Sven Yea, Ill give it a shot.  Why would it be useless?  Maybe the server is used in the backend or maybe I use my own dns to resolve to that IP?  Am I understanding this correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An Elastic IP address is a public IP address, so that takes care of public access.

While you *can* access your instance from within AWS's network with the public ElasticIP address instead of using the private IP address, you'll pay for it:

https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/

> **Data Transfer IN To Amazon EC2 From**
>
> - Amazon EC2, Amazon RDS, Amazon Redshift and Amazon ElastiCache instances or Elastic Network Interfaces in the same Availability Zone
>
>   - Using a private IP address  $0.00 per GB
>   - Using a public or Elastic IP address    $0.01 per GB
>
> **Data Transfer OUT From Amazon EC2 To**
>
> - Amazon EC2, Amazon RDS, Amazon Redshift or Amazon ElastiCache instances,  Amazon Elastic Load Balancing, or Elastic Network
>     Interfaces in the same Availability Zone
>
>   - Using a private IP address  $0.00 per GB
>   - Using a public or Elastic IP address    $0.01 per GB

You don't *need* DNS to access the instance -- the IP alone is sufficient.